# Solve
$\frac{120000}{1+48e^{-0.015t}}=24e^{0.055t}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

This is a challenge problem for Algebra 2 class

> Solve
>   $$\frac{120000}{1+48e^{-0.015t}}=24e^{0.055t}$$

Comment: What have you tried?  Please write an *informative* title, to help others find this problem and its eventual solution.  Also, never post images of text, which cannot be searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy to solve it. However, you can try this:

$$120000=24e^{0.055t}(1+48e^{-0.015t})$$

$$120000=24e^{0.055t}+1152e^{0.04t}$$

Let $x=e^{0.005t}$

$$120000=24x^{11}+1152x^8$$

$$24x^{11}+1152x^8-120000=0$$

So now you find the positive root [(](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=24x%5E11%2B1152x%5E8-120000%3D0)$x\approx 1.76337$)

And $t=200\ln(x)\approx113.446$

Side note: Whoever made this "challenge problem" ... why

Comment: Thank u so much for your help. Can I ask, how did u get the positive root x=1.76337 ?  Is it simply plugging in the equation into a graphing calculator?

Comment: You see that blue $($? Ye, that's a link. But yes, I used wolfram alpha to do so. (Can you accept my answer if it helps? Thanks!) There's no closed form to it I am pretty sure

Comment: how did u know to let x=e^0.005t  ? was it because u knew it could be evenly divided into both .055 and 0.04?  Dang u r a genius.. can I ask what your background is?

Comment: Yes greatest common divisor haha

Comment: Erh im high school y1 but I kinda self learn math too